# GitHub Collaboradores deletando Branchs

Tags: git, github, permissões, branch

No GitHub como configuro para que os colaboradores do meu projeto nao deletem as branchs?
Não existe nenhuma restrição para delete nas settings do projeto.
Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Amigo,

### 1. **No seu repositório você vai em `settings->branches`**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 2. **No menu a esquerda vai em:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 3. **Perto de "Branch protection rules", clica no "add rule":**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 4. **Debaixo "Branch name pattern", digita o nome da branch ou um padrão de proteção que você desejar.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 5. Se você quiser, pode configurar algumas regras de segurança especifica para sua branch. Mas se você fizer até o passo 4, já vai adicionar a proteção que você deseja.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 6. Pra finalizar, só clicar em **Confirmar** ou **Salvar as mudanças**

Traduzido do [Suporte Github configurando as proteções de branches](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-protected-branches)